# How to run angular 6 project with low version mozilla?

Tags: angular, mozilla, angular6

I have `mozilla firefox 31.5.0` version and when I am trying to open `angular 6` project with it I am getting white screen with and 2 log in console.

```
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
```

and

> TypeError: this is undefined.

My big problem is that I can not update my browser(`mozilla`) version. I need any solutions how can I fix it and run my application on this `mozilla` version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `polyfills`

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Which import can I add in my `polyfills`  for the error I wrote earlier?

Comment: Try all of polyfills and see if that helps

Comment: I tried all imports which was commented, but I have same result